# Copiar js de "Dependencies" da node_modules para uma pasta do meu projeto com gulp

Tags: npm, gulp, packages

Eu tenho algumas duvidas referentes a esse "novo" ferramentário do `node/npm`.

Até onde sei/aprendi, eu tenho grandes benefícios de gerenciar os *scripts* `js` pelo `npm`.
Porém eu não acho muito sadio ficar vasculhando a pasta `node_modules` do meu projeto. As vezes percebo quer as bibliotecas de terceiros não possuem um padrão sobre os *paths* de *scripts*. Então queria entender um pouco mais sobre esse tipo de prática: é possível através do `gulp`, eu copiar os arquivos da pasta `node_modules` para um dado diretório de minha necessidade fora dela?

**ex:**

> /node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js para um outro diretório fora
>   da node_modules.

(o `jquery` é realmente só um exemplo.)
Como disse, sei que existem variações nos padrões das pastas.
Então reafirmando minhas dúvidas: existe alguma solução mais "elegante" pra esse cenário? Minha necessidade é "automatizar" uma forma de copiar os *scripts* de terceiros p/ uma pasta de minha necessidade. Também estou ciente de que posso ter entendido esse fluxo de forma errada. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade essa é a ideia de se trabalhar com node_modules e automatizadores de tarefas, segue um exemplo de como eu trabalho com os scripts.

1) Ler todos os scripts do node_module que você quer e compilar todos em um main.JS junto com o seu arquivo de scripts.

```
scripts = [
    'node_modules/prismjs/prism.js',
    'node_modules/flickity/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js',
    'node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js',
    'base/scripts/main.js'
];

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(scripts)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .on('error', gutil.log)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/scripts'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/scripts'));
});
```